# IOS screen is black when storyboard has view controllers

Tags: ios

I have the following story board:

[image: storyboard image]

For some reason the two tabs that have the grey view controller label in the middle of them appear grey compared to the one that does not. (It may be hard to see but there is a 3rd white box with the title "Ratings")

Example of problem:

[image: bugdemo]

Why is this inconsistency happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first two view controllers don't have UIViews inside them. They are just blank view controllers.

Try re-adding a `UIViewController` and hooking it up to your tab bar. By default, a `UIViewController` should come with a `UIVIew` inside.

Or, you could just clone your other one..

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because there is no view for the app to show in the two `UIViewControllers` 'setup', and 'instructions'.

What you might want to do is delete the two `UIViewController`s and then add them back from the object library. You can then ctl-drag from the `UITabBarController` to the `UIViewController`s and select the `view controller` relationship.